# GeoPandas fill polygon gap according to gap area

Tags: python, geopandas, fill, holes

I have several polygons with holes and I would like to fill the gaps with sizes smaller than a certain area

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

# Initializing a polygon with two holes
# See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48770822/how-to-make-holes-in-a-polygon-in-shapely-python-having-polygons
outer = Polygon(((0,0),(20,0),(20,20),(0,20),(0,0)))
inners = (Polygon(((4,4),(4,6),(6,6),(6,4),(4,4))), Polygon(((7,7),(7,8),(8,8),(8,7),(7,7))))
p = Polygon(outer.exterior.coords, [inner.exterior.coords for inner in inners])
gs = gpd.GeoSeries({0: p})
```

For example in this example I would like to eliminate the gaps with an area less than 2

Answer (score 1):

You just need to include a conditional to your list comprehension: `if inner.area>2`

```
p = Polygon(outer.exterior.coords,
            [inner.exterior.coords for inner in inners if inner.area>2])
```